# Exclude method from executing while debugging on Local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure

I am using the following code to cleanup my Azure App's database.

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     core.cleanUpDB();
}
```

Can I prevent this from being executed on my local machine while debugging? I just want to execute this only on the deployed Azure App.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other answers might work in a specific scenario, they don't relate to Windows Azure. The only way to check if you're running in Windows Azure and not running in the emulator (assuming you have a Web Role), is like this:

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable && !RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated)
        core.cleanUpDB();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**HttpRequest.IsLocal**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) to differntiate local and server request.

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
           core.cleanUpDB();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The MSDN articles provides a much better explanation that I could write in the small space here.

Answer (score 0):

in VB.net you would use something like this:

```
'#If DEBUG Then
'only do this while debugging...
'#End If
```

Please remove the ' mark - stack overflow useses the "#" mark as BOLD....
I think it should compile in C# as well.